# How to join two dataframe with both a array column, one's element is nullable, another is not

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframa df1,df2

```
df1
df1's Index was generated by udf function.
+------+----------+
|other |   Index  |
+------+----------+
|     5| [1, 1]   |
|     1| [0, 7]   |
|     2| [1, 7]   |
|     8| [2, 6]   |
|     6| [2, 7]   |   

|-- gridIndex: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)

df2

var l =new ListBuffer[(Int, Array[Int])]
l.append((5,Array(1,1)))
l.append((6,Array(0,7)))
l.append((1,Array(1,7)))
l.append((3,Array(2,6)))
l.append((7,Array(2,7)))

val df2 = l.toDF("other2","Index")

+------+----------+
|other2|   Index  |
+------+----------+
|     5| [1, 1]   |
|     6| [0, 7]   |
|     1| [1, 7]   |
|     3| [2, 6]   |
|     7| [2, 7]   |   

|-- gridIndex: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

I want to join them by Index.
But as you can see a error appear:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Join keys from two sides should have same types**

`df1.Index` is different with `df2.Index`, their `containNull` is different.

So how can i figure out this problem?

I also want to why `|-- element: integer (containsNull = true)` in df2's schema.

Thank you very much!

Comment: what output do you want from above datasets

Comment: df1 join df2, the result is like`index, other1,other2`

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to do this. 
Not sure if this was the desired result as you have not posted the expected output.

```
val df1 = Seq(
            (5,Array(1,1)),
            (1,Array(0,7)),
            (2,Array(1,7)),
            (8,Array(2,6)),
            (6,Array(2,7)),
            (100,Array(null.asInstanceOf[Int],null.asInstanceOf[Int]))
            ).toDF("Other","Index")

val df2 = Seq(
            (5,Array(1,1)),
            (6,Array(0,7)),
            (1,Array(1,7)),
            (3,Array(2,6)),
            (7,Array(null.asInstanceOf[Int],null.asInstanceOf[Int]))
            ).toDF("Other2","Index")

root
 |-- Other: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Index: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)

root
 |-- Other2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Index: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)           

df1.join(df2, df1("Index") <=> df2("Index") ).show() 

+-----+------+------+------+
|Other| Index|Other2| Index|
+-----+------+------+------+
|    5|[1, 1]|     5|[1, 1]|
|    1|[0, 7]|     6|[0, 7]|
|    2|[1, 7]|     1|[1, 7]|
|    8|[2, 6]|     3|[2, 6]|
|  100|[0, 0]|     7|[0, 0]|
+-----+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Yes, your result is what i want see. But if  the dataset  is massvie ,we couldn't convert it to seq one by one as you did. In my question , the only different which cause the error is in df1 `|-- element: integer (containsNull = false)` in df2 `|-- element: integer (containsNull = true)  `